# ASP.NET Listview.selectedindex property goes crazy

Tags: asp.net, listviewitem

I'm deleting a single database record from a listview and after deleting I try to navigate in my listview using listView1.selectedindex property, but I have noticed that it highlights the incorrect record (for example I set listView1.selectedindex to 1 but it displays a record which has index 0) . What is wrong? Please help!

```
protected void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = int.Parse(((Label)ListView1.Items[ListView1.SelectedIndex].FindControl("idLabel")).Text);

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        string Sql = "delete from Employee where id = @id";
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand dCmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, conn))
        {
            dCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            dCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
    BindDataFromBaseToListView();
}
```

BindDataFromBaseToListView method looks so:

```
private void BindDataFromBaseToListView()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter dAd = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Employee", conn))
        {
            DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
            dAd.Fill(dTable); 

            ListView1.DataSourceID = null;
            ListView1.DataSource = dTable;
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
        conn.Close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `deleteButton_Click` event you could use your ListView's `OnItemCommand` event to get the selected row values and delete the item that you want like the code below:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "delete")
    {
        int id = 0;
        if(int.TryParse((e.Item.FindControl("idLabel") as Label).Text, out id))
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                string Sql = "delete from Employee where id = @id";
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand dCmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, conn))
                {
                    dCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                    dCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            BindDataFromBaseToListView();
        }
    }
}
```

And on your control's element will look like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand" .. >
     ...
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="delete" Text="Delete" ID="DeleteButton" />

     ...
```

Let me know if you still have issue with it.